# Select if a child table has no records for given parent IDs

Tags: mysql

I have tables `contracts`, `party` and `doses` (in the order of subordination). I want to select information on doses for parties for certain contracts. Here is my query:

```
select contract_number, comp, ml, party.room, 
  min(doses.begintime), max(doses.endtime), 
  sum(timestampdiff(second, doses.begintime, doses.endtime))/3600. 
  from doses 
    join party 
      on party.id=doses.party_id 
    join contracts 
      on contracts.id=party.contract_id 
  where contracts.id in(97,144,145) 
  group by party.id 
  order by contract_number, party.room;
```

It works fine, but if there is no records in the table `doses` having `party_id` equal to `party.id` then these records are not shown.

The query above gives me 75 results. If not to mention `doses`, there are 103 rows:

```
select contract_number, comp, ml, party.room 
  from party 
  join contracts 
    on contracts.id=party.contract_id 
  where contracts.id in(97,144,145) 
  group by party.id 
  order by contract_number, party.room;
```

How to modify my query to include these omitted results and set min, max, sum to zero?

Comment: try `from party left join doses.......`

Comment: records in `doses` without parent records in `party` are orphan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

```
select contract_number, comp, ml, party.room, 
  min(doses.begintime), max(doses.endtime), 
  sum(timestampdiff(second, doses.begintime, doses.endtime))/3600. 
  from doses 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN party 
      on party.id=doses.party_id 
    join contracts 
      on contracts.id=party.contract_id 
  where contracts.id in(97,144,145) 
  group by party.id 
  order by contract_number, party.room;
```

This will return min, max, sum based on the data held in doses.  If you want these to be Zero when there is no matching party entry then you you could do something like:

`CASE party.room WHEN NULL THEN 0 ELSE min(doses.begintime) END`

Not sure on the syntax for Case, but you can check it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp)

Comment: Thank you, it works and gives me 103 rows, as it should be.